# Load a password-protected webpage 

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am looking for a Cocoa class that will enable me to load a web page (html source) from a given URL.
To make things a bit more complicated I need to be able to set user name and password for this contention since the access to web page is restricted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's basic authentication you can just put the username and password in the URL like so:

```
NSURLRequest *request =
[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://username:password@server.com"]];

[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:NULL error:NULL];
```

Answer (score 5):

[`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) supports the behavior you describe. See [the section on handling authentication challenges](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-160393).

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use [Ben Copsey's ASIHTTPRequest library](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), which works fine both on OSX and the iPhone. 
I know most of the stuff it does can be done with NSURLReqest, but this one just makes life so much easier.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com/top_secret/"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setUsername:@"username"];
[request setPassword:@"password"];
```